# Ruducing a List of objects using Stream.reduce()

Tags: java, list, java-stream

I have a *list* of *objects*, and I need to group objects having `status` equal to my `customizedStatus`to a single customized one with `count` = `sumOfSameObjectsCount` .

We have class `MyObject`

```
class MyObject {
   Integer id;
   String name;
   String status;
   Long count;
   //constructor with attributes
   //getters 
   //setters
}
```

Suggested implementation :

```
List<MyObject> resultList = listOfObjects.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(MyObject::getStatus))
    .entrySet().stream()
    .map(e -> e.getValue().stream()
            .reduce((partialResult,nextElem) -> 
                {
                    LOGGER.info("ahaaaa! inside your reduce block ");
                    if(partialResult.getStatus().equals(customizedStatus)) {
          LOGGER.info("equal to my customizedStatus");
                        return new MyObject(customizedId, customizedName, customizedStatus, partialResult.getCount()+nextElem.getCount());
                    } else {
          LOGGER.info("not equal to my customizedStatus");
                        return new MyObject(partialResult.getId(), partialResult.getName(), partialResult.getStatus(), partialResult.getCount());
                    }
                }
            )
        )
    .map(f -> f.get())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Things work like a charm in case there are multiple objects with `status` equal to my `customizedStatus`. 
Input :

```
[
                    {
                        "id": XX,
                        "name": "nameXX",
                        "status": "statusXX",
                        "count": countXX
                    },
                    {
                        "id": YY,
                        "name": "nameYY",
                        "status": "statusYY",
                        "count": countYY
                    },
                    {
                        "id": ZZ,
                        "name": "nameZZ",
                        "status": "customizedStatus",
                        "count": countZZ
                    },
                    {
                        "id": ZZz,
                        "name": "nameZZz",
                        "status": "customizedStatus",
                        "count": countZZz
                    }
                ]
```

Output :

```
[
                    {
                        "id": XX,
                        "name": "nameXX",
                        "status": "statusXX",
                        "count": countXX
                    },
                    {
                        "id": YY,
                        "name": "nameYY",
                        "status": "statusYY",
                        "count": countYY
                    },
                    {
                        "id": customizedId,
                        "name": "customizedName",
                        "status": "customizedStatus",
                        "count": countZZ+countZZz
                    }
                ]
```

In case there is one object with `status` equal to my `customizedStatus`, need to be customized it too, unfortunately reduce block is being skipped ! 
Input :

```
[
                    {
                        "id": XX,
                        "name": "nameXX",
                        "status": "statusXX",
                        "count": countXX
                    },
                    {
                        "id": YY,
                        "name": "nameYY",
                        "status": "statusYY",
                        "count": countYY
                    },
                    {
                        "id": ZZ,
                        "name": "nameZZ",
                        "status": "customizedStatus",
                        "count": countZZ
                    }
                ]
```

Output :

```
[
                    {
                        "id": XX,
                        "name": "nameXX",
                        "status": "statusXX",
                        "count": countXX
                    },
                    {
                        "id": YY,
                        "name": "nameYY",
                        "status": "statusYY",
                        "count": countYY
                    },
                    {
                        "id": ZZ,
                        "name": "nameZZ",
                        "status": "customizedStatus",
                        "count": countZZ
                    }
                ]
```

Expected output :

```
[
                    {
                        "id": XX,
                        "name": "nameXX",
                        "status": "statusXX",
                        "count": countXX
                    },
                    {
                        "id": YY,
                        "name": "nameYY",
                        "status": "statusYY",
                        "count": countYY
                    },
                    {
                        "id": customizedId,
                        "name": "customizedName",
                        "status": "customizedStatus",
                        "count": countZZ
                    }
                ]
```

It seems like reduce is executed in case there is multiple objects with same `status`, if there isn't reduce not being executed at all ! 
 Any thoughts to get the expected output using `groupBy` and `reduce` ?

Comment: Your recent editing doesn't provide enough information on what the final result should look like. A list containing a single object per status? What's wrong with the code you've posted?

Comment: @Alexander Ivanchenko question edited, hope is clear now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Update

The resulting type is not correct. Because you didn't provide the identity within the `reduce()` it will return an `Optional<Object>`, but not an object.

For the same reason (because you are using a flavor of `reduce()` that doesn't expect identity), the *accumulator* will have no impact on a **single** element. A quote from the [*documentation*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce(java.util.function.BinaryOperator)):

> Performs a reduction on the elements of this stream, using an
> associative accumulation function, and returns an Optional describing
> the reduced value, if any. This is equivalent to:
>
> ```
>  boolean foundAny = false;
>  T result = null;
>  for (T element : this stream) {
>      if (!foundAny) {
>          foundAny = true;
>          result = element;
>      }
>      else
>          result = accumulator.apply(result, element);
>  }
>  return foundAny ? Optional.of(result) : Optional.empty();
> ```

The first encountered stream element would become a partial result and there's no more elements, it would be wrapped by the optional as is and returned.

A possible remedy is to introduce the *identity*:

```
public static final Integer customizedId = 99;
public static final String customizedName = "customizedName";
public static final String customizedStatus = "customizedStatus";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<MyObject> listOfObjects =
        List.of(new MyObject(1, "nameXX", "statusXX", 1L),
                new MyObject(2, "nameYY", "statusYY", 1L),
                new MyObject(3, "nameZZz", "customizedStatus", 3L));
    
    List<MyObject> result =
        listOfObjects.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(MyObject::getStatus))
            .entrySet().stream()
            .map(e -> e.getValue().stream()
                .reduce(getIdentity(e), (partialResult, nextElem) -> accumulate(partialResult, nextElem)) )
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
        
    result.forEach(System.out::println);
}

public static MyObject getIdentity(Map.Entry<String, List<MyObject>> entry) {
        
    return entry.getKey().equals(customizedStatus) ?
            new MyObject(customizedId, customizedName, customizedStatus, 0L) :
            entry.getValue().iterator().next();
}
    
public static MyObject accumulate(MyObject result, MyObject next) {
        
    return result.getStatus().equals(customizedStatus) ?
            new MyObject(customizedId, customizedName, customizedStatus, result.getCount() + next.getCount()) :
            new MyObject(result.getId(), result.getName(), result.getStatus(), result.getCount());
}
```

*Output:*

```
MyObject{id=2, name='nameYY', status='statusYY', count=1}
MyObject{id=1, name='nameXX', status='statusXX', count=1}
MyObject{id=99, name='customizedName', status='customizedStatus', count=3}
```

*You can play around with this* [*Online demo*](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/r9U)

But keep in mind that it's not the brightest idea to try to crap a lot of conditional logic into stream because it becomes more difficult to read.

*Solutions provided below were written before the question was updated, and the problem was clarified. Although, they don't target this specific problem, someone might benefit from them and for that reason I'll preserve them.*

#### Reducing the list into a single object

> Is there any solution to make it pass by reduce even listOfObjects entries are different by status ?

In case if you want to reduce a list of objects into a single object with a predefined `id`, `name` and `status`, there's no need to create an intermediate map with `Collectors.groupingBy()`.

If you want to utilize `reduce()` operation for that, you can accumulate `count` and then create a resulting object based on it:

That's how it might look like (the type of dummy object was changed to `MyObject` to avoid confusion with `java.lang.Object`):

```
final Integer customizedId =    // intializing the resulting id
final String customizedName =   // intializing the resulting name
final String customizedStatus = // intializing the resulting status
        
List<MyObject> listOfObjects =  // intializing the source list
    
MyObject resultingObject = listOfObjects.stream()
    .map(MyObject::getCount)
    .reduce(Long::sum)
    .map(count -> new MyObject(customizedId,  customizedName, customizedStatus, 0L))
    .orElseThrow(); // or .orElse(() -> new MyObject(customizedId,  customizedName, customizedStatus, 0L));
```

Another way of achieving it is to make use of the fact that `MyObject` is mutable and utilize it as a container inside the `collect()` operation:

```
MyObject resultingObject = listOfObjects.stream()
    .collect(() -> new MyObject(customizedId,  customizedName, customizedStatus, 0L),
        (MyObject result, MyObject next) -> result.setCount(result.getCount() + next.getCount()),
        (left, right) -> left.setCount(left.getCount() + right.getCount()));
```

Comment: Thank you @Alexander Ivanchenko for your quick reply, well actually I don't need to reduce my list of objects into a single one, my purpose is to reduce objects having the same `status` as my `customizedStatus` with predifined `id`, `name`, `status` and of course the sum of `count` of this objects, and leave the other entries untouchable. I've edited my question with a peace of code maybe it gives a better view for the issue.

Comment: @HEssaidi This phrase: `reduce even listOfObjects entries are different by status` is misleading. Please rephrase it, and specify what should be the **type** of the result (*a list of objects*) ?

Comment: @HEssaidi As a result, you want to get a single object per status?

Comment: @HEssaidi Updated the answer and provided a demo.

Comment: I khnew it ! I knew that I've been skipping something !!!! `getIdentity` is the missing piece. I had the idea to customize first `listOfObjects` objects having the same `status` as `customizedStatus` and then start `groupingBy` and `reduce` operations, but your solution covers all the logic behind. Thank you mate

Comment: Regarding the resulting type ! yes is not correct, my bad I forgot to add `.map(f -> f.get())`

Comment: @HEssaidi *forgot to add `.map(f -> f.get())`* - Well, if you're expecting the result to be always present in the optional object (and because of that don't checking it), it's a good practice  to use `orElseThrow()` instead. Both `get()` and `orElseThrow()` will throw `NoSuchElementException`, but the later method shows your intention clearly while reading the code.